# Number of cycles of a battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I want to calculate the number of cycles that my battery has reached during its life in my PV plant. In the datasheet is indicated that the state of charge minimum is 10% and the maximum is 100% and that the maximum number of cycles is 5000, after that it starts to decrease his capacity until the change of it. I want to know if it has reached 5000 cycles. It is not clear if for cycle is indicated the charge and discharge of the battery from 10% to 100% or 2 times the nominal energy that is charge and discharge the battery from 0% to 100%. Do you know what is exactly a cycle of a battery? Is there someone that has experience with solar panel and batteries?

Comment: Hmm you'll want to check out batteryuniversity.com.  The batteries constantly depreciate any time they are charged, discharge, or even stored.  They will be rated to have a certain amount of the original capacity or Cold Cranking Amps at the end of 5000 cycles, often 80%.

Comment: @KH Yes I know it, but I didn't understand if with a cycle is intended charging and discharging from 0% to 100% and from 100% to 0% the nominal capacity of the battery or it is intended the same but between the minimum and maximum state of charge that in this case is 10% and 100%

Comment: You need to find the datasheet for the exact model of your battery.